# On Linux, can I forward wlan0 to eth0, and wlan1 to eth1?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I have the following simple situation: two internet connections via two distinct ethernet NICs, *eth0* and *eth1*, and two APs (I use hostapd, of course) on two distinct wireless cards, *wlan0* and *wlan1*. The two wifi cards have different subnets (192.168.53.0/24, 10.0.15.0/24), and the two ethernet cards are on different subnets (192.168.1.0/24, 10.10.2.0/24).

I would like to keep forwarding completely separate, in other words:

```
   wlan0 --> eth0
   wlan1 --> eth1
```

I know how to bind applications to different interfaces, and how to use policy routing. What I do not know is whether I can use iptables to forward as above, or I absolutely need to use Policy Routing to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need policy routing.

Ordinary routing will choose the next-hop address or interface based on the destination address and nothing else. That is, all packets to the same address will use the same route.

Once you use other factors like the inbound interface to influence the routing decision, you are by definition performing policy routing.

[netfilter/iptables do have an addon providing a "ROUTE" target](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.5) to do PBR with netfilter alone, but its adoption, maintenance and testing are poor relative to the typical iproute2 rule-based approach. As even the netfilter maintainers say there,

> "Whenever possible, you should use the MARK target together with
>   iproute2 instead of this [iptables] ROUTE target."